# How can I recognize an Icecast stream from an Shoutcast?

Tags: shoutcast

Lot of radios are using the icecast or shoutcast ... but what is the way to know if a a stream is using one or the other ?

I have problems to stream some radios and i think knowing this is a first important step

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHOUTcast servers start their response with `ICY`.  Icecast servers start with `HTTP/1.0`.  There are servers that clone both of these methods.  You can use a packet sniffer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see this for yourself.